# Rails re-renders with screwed up params when I refresh the page

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a page called bulk_edit. It has a route of:

```
   post :bulk_edit
```

In my routes.rb.

The view itself is in HAML and comes up a-okay. I also have a method in my controller called bulk_edit:

```
def bulk_edit
  print_method
  assets = params[:assets] || ''
  @assets = VodAsset.where(id: assets.split(','))
end
```

VodAsset is one of my models. The problem is, when I get to my page and then hit refresh, pandemonium occurs - I get this:

[image: Bizarre error... never do I pass this]

My show method is as such:

```
def show
    print_method
    @options = VodAsset.all.map { |a| [a.id, a.title_asset_id] }.to_h
end
```

Pretty innocuous as far as I can tell. id is a key for my model (as it is for all models) called VodAsset. I cannot understand how in any scenario, refresh or otherwise, we end up trying to render with id->bulk_edit? Somehow the method name is getting into the actual call, which makes zero sense, especially with the very simple setup I have right now.

I am just hitting refresh page... was wondering, where would I start to be able to troubleshoot this problem? There does not seem to be enough going on to warrant this error. The stack trace on the ole red page has not 1 single line that has anything to do with my controller code, or any code that is in my project, so it is not a very good starting point.

Here is the whole stacktrace - but I can't make anything of it since it doesn't have anything about any code in files that I have written:

```
activerecord (4.2.3) lib/active_record/core.rb:155:in `find'
cancancan (2.0.0) lib/cancan/model_adapters/abstract_adapter.rb:20:in `find'
cancancan (2.0.0) lib/cancan/controller_resource.rb:104:in `find_resource'
cancancan (2.0.0) lib/cancan/controller_resource.rb:63:in `load_resource_instance'
cancancan (2.0.0) lib/cancan/controller_resource.rb:35:in `load_resource'
cancancan (2.0.0) lib/cancan/controller_resource.rb:28:in `load_and_authorize_resource'
cancancan (2.0.0) lib/cancan/controller_resource.rb:12:in `block in add_before_action'
activesupport (4.2.3) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:446:in `instance_exec'
activesupport (4.2.3) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:446:in `block in make_lambda'
activesupport (4.2.3) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:162:in `block in halting'
activesupport (4.2.3) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:502:in `block in call'
activesupport (4.2.3) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:502:in `each'
activesupport (4.2.3) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:502:in `call'
activesupport (4.2.3) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:88:in `run_callbacks'
actionpack (4.2.3) lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:19:in `process_action'
actionpack (4.2.3) lib/action_controller/metal/rescue.rb:29:in `process_action'
actionpack (4.2.3) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:32:in `block in process_action'
activesupport (4.2.3) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:164:in `block in instrument'
activesupport (4.2.3) lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:20:in `instrument'
activesupport (4.2.3) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:164:in `instrument'
actionpack (4.2.3) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:30:in `process_action'
actionpack (4.2.3) lib/action_controller/metal/params_wrapper.rb:250:in `process_action'
activerecord (4.2.3) lib/active_record/railties/controller_runtime.rb:18:in `process_action'
actionpack (4.2.3) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:137:in `process'
actionview (4.2.3) lib/action_view/rendering.rb:30:in `process'
actionpack (4.2.3) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:196:in `dispatch'
actionpack (4.2.3) lib/action_controller/metal/rack_delegation.rb:13:in `dispatch'
actionpack (4.2.3) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:237:in `block in action'
actionpack (4.2.3) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:76:in `dispatch'
actionpack (4.2.3) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:45:in `serve'
actionpack (4.2.3) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:43:in `block in serve'
actionpack (4.2.3) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:30:in `each'
actionpack (4.2.3) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:30:in `serve'
actionpack (4.2.3) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:821:in `call'
bullet (5.6.0) lib/bullet/rack.rb:10:in `call'
warden (1.2.7) lib/warden/manager.rb:36:in `block in call'
warden (1.2.7) lib/warden/manager.rb:35:in `catch'
warden (1.2.7) lib/warden/manager.rb:35:in `call'
rack (1.6.8) lib/rack/etag.rb:24:in `call'
rack (1.6.8) lib/rack/conditionalget.rb:25:in `call'
rack (1.6.8) lib/rack/head.rb:13:in `call'
actionpack (4.2.3) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/params_parser.rb:27:in `call'
actionpack (4.2.3) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/flash.rb:260:in `call'
rack (1.6.8) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:225:in `context'
rack (1.6.8) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:220:in `call'
actionpack (4.2.3) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/cookies.rb:560:in `call'
activerecord (4.2.3) lib/active_record/query_cache.rb:36:in `call'
activerecord (4.2.3) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:653:in `call'
activerecord (4.2.3) lib/active_record/migration.rb:377:in `call'
actionpack (4.2.3) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:29:in `block in call'
activesupport (4.2.3) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:84:in `run_callbacks'
actionpack (4.2.3) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:27:in `call'
actionpack (4.2.3) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/reloader.rb:73:in `call'
actionpack (4.2.3) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/remote_ip.rb:78:in `call'
actionpack (4.2.3) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:17:in `call'
web-console (2.3.0) lib/web_console/middleware.rb:28:in `block in call'
web-console (2.3.0) lib/web_console/middleware.rb:18:in `catch'
web-console (2.3.0) lib/web_console/middleware.rb:18:in `call'
actionpack (4.2.3) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:30:in `call'
railties (4.2.3) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:38:in `call_app'
railties (4.2.3) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in `block in call'
activesupport (4.2.3) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:68:in `block in tagged'
activesupport (4.2.3) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:26:in `tagged'
activesupport (4.2.3) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:68:in `tagged'
railties (4.2.3) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in `call'
quiet_assets (1.1.0) lib/quiet_assets.rb:27:in `call_with_quiet_assets'
actionpack (4.2.3) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:21:in `call'
rack (1.6.8) lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:22:in `call'
rack (1.6.8) lib/rack/runtime.rb:18:in `call'
activesupport (4.2.3) lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache_middleware.rb:28:in `call'
rack (1.6.8) lib/rack/lock.rb:17:in `call'
actionpack (4.2.3) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:116:in `call'
rack (1.6.8) lib/rack/sendfile.rb:113:in `call'
railties (4.2.3) lib/rails/engine.rb:518:in `call'
railties (4.2.3) lib/rails/application.rb:165:in `call'
rack (1.6.8) lib/rack/content_length.rb:15:in `call'
unicorn (5.3.0) lib/unicorn/http_server.rb:606:in `process_client'
unicorn (5.3.0) lib/unicorn/http_server.rb:702:in `worker_loop'
unicorn (5.3.0) lib/unicorn/http_server.rb:549:in `spawn_missing_workers'
unicorn (5.3.0) lib/unicorn/http_server.rb:142:in `start'
unicorn-rails (2.2.1) lib/unicorn_rails.rb:33:in `run'
rack (1.6.8) lib/rack/server.rb:287:in `start'
railties (4.2.3) lib/rails/commands/server.rb:80:in `start'
railties (4.2.3) lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:80:in `block in server'
railties (4.2.3) lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:75:in `tap'
railties (4.2.3) lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:75:in `server'
railties (4.2.3) lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:39:in `run_command!'
railties (4.2.3) lib/rails/commands.rb:17:in `<top (required)>'
bin/rails:8:in `require'
bin/rails:8:in `<top (required)>'
spring (2.0.2) lib/spring/client/rails.rb:28:in `load'
spring (2.0.2) lib/spring/client/rails.rb:28:in `call'
spring (2.0.2) lib/spring/client/command.rb:7:in `call'
spring (2.0.2) lib/spring/client.rb:30:in `run'
spring (2.0.2) bin/spring:49:in `<top (required)>'
spring (2.0.2) lib/spring/binstub.rb:31:in `load'
spring (2.0.2) lib/spring/binstub.rb:31:in `<top (required)>'
/Users/philjohnson/.rbenv/versions/2.3.3/lib/ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:68:in `require'
/Users/philjohnson/.rbenv/versions/2.3.3/lib/ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:68:in `require'
bin/spring:13:in `<top (required)>'
bin/rails:3:in `load'
bin/rails:3:in `<main>'
```

Comment: Are you meaning to render the bulk_edit template after the post? Or should it redirect?

Comment: @maxpleaner I want it to render in this case

Comment: looks like your url is wrong

Comment: It would be helpful for you to show the stack trace of the error, to know which line caused it, but I figure it's probably `VodAsset.where(id: assets.split(','))`. It's unclear how `params[:assets]` is being set (maybe you accidentally hard-coded something in the template?)

Comment: @maxpleaner what really bothers me is I've put a log message in bulk_edit that indicates what's in assets. When I hit refresh, this log message doesn't appear - it doesn't even hit the method the second time at all. I don't understand at all the flow of control when I hit that refresh button. I have confirmed that neither show nor bulk_edit are visited when I hit refresh. index also does not get touched. The log message on the error page indicates that it is bad data being pushed to show, but I guess it comes up with the error before the control flow actually comes to show.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm going to assume a more full example of your routes file looks something like:

```
resources :vod_assets do
  collection do
    post :bulk_edit
  end
end
```

this will result in a bunch of routes for VOD assets, the 2 of interest to us are:

```
              Prefix Verb URI Pattern                     Controller#Action
bulk_edit_vod_assets POST /vod_assets/bulk_edit(.:format) vod_assets#bulk_edit
           vod_asset GET  /vod_assets/:id(.:format)       vod_assets#show
```

When we look at the routes this way, we can see that one is a `POST` and one is a `GET`. If you were to try and do a `GET` to `/vod_assets/bulk_edit`, it **would not** match the `POST /vod_assets/bulk_edit` route but it *would* match `GET  /vod_assets/:id` with the `id` being `"bulk_edit"`. That would then send you to the `show` action on your controller, but you have a `before_action` somewhere (looks like something `cancan` related) that tries to load the `VodAsset` using `params[:id]` which is now `"bulk_edit"`.

So, when you refresh the page this is happening because the browser is sending a `GET` instead of a `POST` and you aren't hitting the route you expect to, because the verb doesn't match.

If you'd like you could set up some constraints on your routes to prevent `"bulk_edit"` from going to the `show` route, something like this should do it (untested):

```
resources :vod_assets, constraints: { id: /[[:digit:]]/ } do
  collection do
    post :bulk_edit
  end
end
```

and now when you refresh, you should get a `No route matches` error instead of the current error.

Comment: Wow. You guessed precisely what I had going on. Thanks so much.